# Is it possible to add my app to the photo album's 'share via' button?

Tags: ios, photo

I've worked on an Android application that enable to send pics directly via the album photo. Just have to add a link to my app in the share via button.

Now I'm doing the same app for iPhone. That's why I want to know if that is possible to put my app to the list of propositions in that share via button.

Comment: no, you can't modify the "Photo Album"

Comment: Are you sure it is not possible?!